# Trees have a vertex of degree $1$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Prove that any tree has a vertex of degree $1$.

Let graph $G=(V,E)$ have $n$ vertices and $m$ edges where $m<n$. We need to prove that the minimum degree of, $\delta (G)=1$

Since G is connected then there exists a path from $u$ to $v$ such that $u,v \in V$.

Is what I have said so far correct? I really don't know how to carry it on. I need a formal answer.

Comment: Your *otherwise* remark doesn’t really make sense: adding edges can never **dis**connect a graph

Comment: Think about starting at one vertex and then moving to a neighbor, never repeating an edge.  If all your vertices have degree at least 2 what happens?  Will you eventually get back to some vertex you have already seen?

Comment: If every vertex has degree at least 2, then how many edges would there be?

Comment: If every vertex has degree of at least 2, then a cycle would exist?

Comment: Every tree  $\underline{\mbox{with at least two vertices}}$ has a vertex of degree $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, you can say more. Any tree has at least 2 vertices of degree 1.

Proof: Since $G$ is a tree, $G$ is connected. Let $P=\{u=v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1},v_n=v\}$ be a $u-v$ path of maximum length. Clearly $u$ is adjacent to $v_1$ and $v$ is adjacent to $v_{n-1}$ so that $\deg(u)\ge1$ and $\deg(v)\ge 1$.

Now $u$ cannot be adjacent to any other vertices in $G$ not on $P$ because then we could extend $P$ to a longer path in $G$. Similarly $v$ cannot be adjacent to any other vertex in $G$ not on $P$.

Neither $u$ nor $v$ can be adjacent to any other vertices in $P$ other than $v_1$ and $v_{n-1}$ because that would induce a cycle in $G$, which contradicts the assumption that $G$ is a tree.

Thus $\deg(u)=1$ and $\deg(v)=1$.

Answer (score 4):

This is trivial: every tree has n-1 edges, where n is the number of vertices. If every vertices has degree at least 2 the sum of the degree is at least 2n.So there are at least n edges. Impossible.

Comment: is that using the handshaking lemma?

Comment: If you refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma, then yes it is using that Lemma.

Answer (score 3):

How you make the argument will depend to some extent on what you already know about trees. One approach that uses nothing beyond the definition — a tree is a connected, acyclic graph — is to show that if $G$ has no vertex of degree $1$, then you can construct a cycle in $G$. Start at any vertex and keep moving to a new one as long as you can; there are only finitely many vertices altogether, so at some point ...